# PowerShell Script to Return Employee's Manager and their Manager (x5)

Tags: powershell

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$user = Read-Host "[ USER_NAME ]"
Get-ADUser -identity $user -Properties * |
Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,Title, Department, @{label='Manager';expression={$_.manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}} |format-list
```

This is the preliminary part, but I do not understand how to make the script provide the manager of the manager (x5)and then export to csv. I do want to see Title, Manager, Department, and FirstName LastName for each manager.

Comment: Omit `|format-list` and share a [mcve] incl. _sanitized_ output.

Comment: Alright, but how do I now get the script to show the manager of the first resulting manager? For example, User A has manager X, how do I then find out manager x's manager? (x5)

Comment: Recursively call something like `Get-ADUser -identity $_.manager` while it gives sense?