# Powershell - ActiveDirectory Find LastLogon and Manager for all users in OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to get LastLogon in a human readable form for all users in an OU and also their manager. Generally people will Logon to the local Domain Controller Server - so if I could limit to checking just the local one DCLocal would be fine.

So I have this (note I have TimeStamp - I don't want this as it is too far out of possible compliance - I need to be accurate within 1 day not 14 and not 19 but 1 day.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -SearchBase "OU=STAFF,OU=MINE,DC=mine,DC=local" 
-ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,lastLogonTimestamp | Select CN,@{n="lastLogonTimeStamp";e=
{[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} | Export-CSV -NoType c:\temp\lastLogin.csv
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this , I have looked at this [PowerShell Script to Return Employee's Manager and their Manager (x5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958386/powershell-script-to-return-employees-manager-and-their-manager-x5)
I am not sure how to integrate that with what I have.

How can I do both of these functions [LastLogon and Manager] and limit the domain controllers to the local box and OU's as I have in my example code.

Following Abraham's advice below
I have tried

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -Server MYLDC01 
-SearchBase "OU=STAFF,OU=MINE,DC=mine,DC=local" 
-ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,LastLogon, Manager | Select 
CN,@{n="LastLogon";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}
, Manager} | Export-CSV -NoType c:\temp\lastLogon.csv
```

Which results in

```
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:238
+ ... astLogon";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}, Manager} | Expo ...
+   

                                                    ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Manager' in expression or statement.
```

Comment: You'll need to query _every single domain controller_ to calculate the real value of `LastLogonTimestamp`

Comment: Add `Manager` to the property field to query, then select it with the rest of the selected items. For better output, place it in a calculated property and query the display name instead. Same thing for the `lastlogon` attribute, just change the method on `datetime` to the proper utc time conversion. Also, `Get-ADUser` cmdlets query only one server, not multiple. You can also specify which one to query from using the `-Server` parameter.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala do you have a sample of what you are telling me - I am not a powershell guru : would this be it  -prop CN,lastLogonTimestamp, Manager, Select {m=manager, n=blah.
Where does -Server go after my -SearchBase ? then convert date (LastLogon is numbers - to UTC how to do that ?)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - as noted I do not want LastLogonTimeStamp - just LastLogon - I posted what I have that is runnable code,.

Comment: You've enclosed the manager property within the `lastlogon` calculated property. Separate the two, other than that, looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat:
The only way to ascertain the actual last logon time is to query EVERY domain controller, though it will be *somewhat* right if you have every subnet properly configured along with its local Domain Controller in AD Sites and Services so that the user's logon DC *should* be the local one.

I have a script which querys the DC logs and finds exact logon time and the machine they used but it does obviously take a LONG time to run so is used in troubleshooting single users rather than run regularly.

That said - you must also be careful when copy-pasting code from the web that you grab only what you need, espcially if it's a snippet of a larger script - unexpected line breaks and brackets in the incorrect places will render the script useless:

Compare this with your pasted code and keep it on a single line - it should work ok as far as it goes:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -Server MyDC -SearchBase "OU=TheseUsers,OU=MyUsers,DC=my,DC=local" -ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,LastLogon, Manager | Select CN,@{n="LastLogon";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}}, Manager
```

Comment: I believe the users login will always be the local one. I really need it to be a fairly quick run - I don't have that many local users < 200 ; however rules are in place that require login every 30 days or else lots of extra work for me happens. To prevent that - I need this info to notify management of who needs to login. This is why I need the accurate Logon Date and also the manager.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you, I created it to help me do the same that you are requesting

```ps
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$properties = ("Name", "SamAccountName", "mail", "lastLogon", "manager", "company", "createTimeStamp", "department", "logonCount", "pwdLastSet", "userPrincipalName", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "employeeID", "accountExpires", "division", "msDS-ResultantPSO")
$users = @{}

foreach ($hostname in (Get-ADDomainController -Filter { IsReadOnly -eq $false } ).HostName) {
    foreach ($user in (Get-ADUser -Server $hostname -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -properties $properties | Select-Object $properties)) {
        if ( $users.Item($user.SamAccountName)) {
            If ( $user.lastLogon -gt $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon ) { $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon = $user.lastLogon }
            $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).logonCount += $user.logonCount
        }
        else {
            $users.Add( $user.SamAccountName, $user )
        }
    }
}

$hostname = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -NextClosestSite).HostName
foreach ( $user in $users.Values ) {
    if ( $user.lastLogon ) { $user.lastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.lastLogon) }
    if ( $user.pwdLastSet ) { $user.pwdLastSet = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.pwdLastSet) }
    if ( $user.accountExpires -eq "9223372036854775807" -or $user.accountExpires -eq "0" ) { $user.accountExpires = "never expires" }
    else {
        $user.accountExpires = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.accountExpires) 
    }
    if ( $user.manager ) { $user.manager = (Get-ADUser $user.manager -Server "$hostname" -properties Name ).Name }
}

$users.Values | Export-Csv -Path C:\ins\users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```